# python socket drop packet if certain bytes detected while receiving packet

Tags: python, sockets, stream

I have this simple python script

```
sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET,socket.SOCK_DGRAM)
sock.sendto(b'ok',('123.123.123.123',1234))
recv,addr = sock.recvfrom(128) # This line is receiving packet?
```

How do I handle packet while it's in down streaming?
I mean I want ignore packet  if certain bytes detected for example `b'\xfc'`

I can achieve it **AFTER** the buffer/data completely received with doing this:

```
if b'\xfc' in recv: sock.close()
```

But this weakness is I need to wait data/buffer completely received, what if destination server reply with big packet size? This will not efficient, I need to fully received destination server reply before close.

If my question is hard to understand, just understand this analogy. Suppose you want talk to me, and I'm starting listening you. While you are talking, I'm processing every your character, if there's certain character for example letter 's' you told to me, I will close  my ear suddenly exactly after you send me such character.

Comment: I believe I should use ```socket.STREAM``` instead of ```socket.SOCK_DGRAM```. But I want use UDP? Can stream act like UDP?

Comment: Or my question is how to limit received data to 3bytes. If I get reply 3 byte data then I should close sock asap.

Comment: You can't receive more than about 1500 bytes at a time via UDP. Your fears are imaginary.

Comment: I know about it, but that's not what am I talking about. I'm talking about closing connection in UDP